# How to find Google Sheets pivot table's colum and row headers?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, pivot-table, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO9U9.png)

I want to create a pivot table in google sheets which uses "shirts names" as it's columns headers, "people names" as it's rows headers(as showen in the image).
The value should be different in every cell - The sheet gets info about a person and which shirt did he take. In the pivot-table's cell aligned with the person's name, and the name of the shirt, needs to be written "used" or "available".

The formula I need is actually the value in every cell in the pivot's table, so every cell needs to somehow understand which column and row is he in.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
=IF('stats'!D8="borrowed", IF(B2 = 'stats'!E8, "used", "available"), B2)
```

Answer (score 0):

to search for header reference:

[image: 0]

---

to get the column range reference under the searched header:

[image: 0]

---

to convert above references to the actual ones, wrap them into `INDIRECT`

Comment: It works fine in the sheet "stats" but when I try to use the formula in pivot-table's values formula in another sheet - It says: _Did not find value 'shirt's name' in MATCH evaluation._

Comment: that's because you need to use proper references: `=INDIRECT("stats!"&ADDRESS(21, MATCH(A25, stats!A20:20, 0), 4)&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS(A:A), MATCH(A25, stats!A20:20, 0), 4))`